# how to restart main activity while retaining some data

Tags: java, android

This is my first app and I'm trying to write a simple Liar's Dice game.

I wrote everything in the main activity class, rolls random dice, textedit boxes to enter bids and buttons to bid and call.

So after the game runs, how do I get it to keep track of the score and run again?

I've tried making another activity screen with a restart button and have it go there after the game ends so I can restart the main activity. However I am able to press back(phonekey) from that screen and get stuck at the end of the previous game.

Also I am trying to use an array to keep track of the wins and losses but not sure how to go about bringing it back and forth from the activities.

Comment: I'd rather save gamedata to some database and then reset the games components than restarting the whole activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To restart main activity you can do

```
finish();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), YourMainActivity.class));// then call again
```

and retain your data by using preferences or sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Well you can just make a global array that holds the numbers, and just have a method run when a user clicks a Button or whatever you want to trigger the roll. An easy way to show you would be

```
<Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android: layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Touch Me"
    android:on click="leRoll" />
```

Then in your Activity you can have a method called `leRoll` which is triggered when the button "touch me" is clicked on. All the saving scored could be done in there using the global array.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this is what you are looking for but:

You could override the back button to go to the screen of the second activity.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
  Intent intentstart = new Intent(Activity2.this, MainActivity.class);
  intentstart.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  startActivity(intentstart);
  return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you keep track of your wins and losses in a SQLite database.  It may sound like overkill, but it's ideally suited to storing an arbitrary number of repeated, structured bits of data.  If that's too much overhead, then open a File and append new game scores to the end, or store them in an array of Strings in SharedPreferences.  Any of these three is a good choice for storing a simple vector of values, where you don't know ahead of time how many values there may be, and you can read them from any part of your Application.

You should use SharedPreference to save the current game state so that your game Activity can display the right thing each time you come back to it.  As soon as a game ends, write the SharedPreference value for game state, to say that the player is at the end of a game.  Then, when the Activity next starts up, it will know to begin a new game.